# Fail to open outlook 2013 application using OleClientSite API in eclipe

Tags: java, eclipse, outlook

Code :-

```
public static void sendEMail() {
    Display display = Display.getCurrent();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    OleFrame frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
    // This should start outlook if it is not running yet
    OleClientSite site = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "OVCtl.OVCtl");
    site.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);
    // now get the outlook application
    OleClientSite site2 = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Outlook.Application");
    OleAutomation outlook = new OleAutomation(site2);
    //
    OleAutomation mail = invoke(outlook, "CreateItem", 0 /* Mail item */).getAutomation();
    setProperty(mail, "To", "test@gmail.com"); /*
                                                * Empty but could also be predefined
                                                */
    setProperty(mail, "Bcc", "test@gmail.com"); /*
                                                 * Empty but could also be predefined
                                                 */
    setProperty(mail, "BodyFormat", 2 /* HTML */);
    setProperty(mail, "Subject", "Top News for you");
    setProperty(mail, "HtmlBody", "<html>Hello<p>, please find some infos here.</html>");
    File file = new File("c:/temp/test.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
      OleAutomation attachments = getProperty(mail, "Attachments");
      invoke(attachments, "Add", "c:/temp/test.txt");
    }
    else {
      MessageDialog.openInformation(shell, "Info",
          "Attachment File c:/temp/test.txt not found; will send email with attachment");
    }
    invoke(mail, "Display" /* or "Send" */);

  }

  private static OleAutomation getProperty(final OleAutomation auto, final String name) {
    Variant varResult = auto.getProperty(property(auto, name));
    if ((varResult != null) && (varResult.getType() != OLE.VT_EMPTY)) {
      OleAutomation result = varResult.getAutomation();
      varResult.dispose();
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }

  private static Variant invoke(final OleAutomation auto, final String command, final String value) {
    return auto.invoke(property(auto, command), new Variant[] { new Variant(value) });
  }

  private static Variant invoke(final OleAutomation auto, final String command) {
    return auto.invoke(property(auto, command));
  }

  private static Variant invoke(final OleAutomation auto, final String command, final int value) {
    return auto.invoke(property(auto, command), new Variant[] { new Variant(value) });
  }

  private static boolean setProperty(final OleAutomation auto, final String name, final String value) {
    return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
  }

  private static boolean setProperty(final OleAutomation auto, final String name, final int value) {
    return auto.setProperty(property(auto, name), new Variant(value));
  }

  private static int property(final OleAutomation auto, final String name) {
    return auto.getIDsOfNames(new String[] { name })[0];
  }
```

The above code works fine in `eclipse indigo` version but when I execute same code on any other version(`mars`).
I am getting following exception:-

> Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to create Ole Client. result = -2147221164
>       at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE.error(OLE.java:302)
>       at org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite.(OleClientSite.java:275)
>       at mail.ole.OutlookMail.sendEMail(OutlookMail.java:31)
>       at mail.ole.OutlookMail.main(OutlookMail.java:17)

I have searched for the solution on google but didn't get any answers. please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: -2147221164 is 0x80040154 which is the OLE error code for 'class is not registered'

Comment: Thank you for your reply. is there any way to register that class?

Comment: any one knows how to solve the above problem(OLE error)??